# DeReference Environment Variables on Remote Server not on Local Server

Tags: rest, curl, post, get, environment-variables

I have set of environment variables in get/post data call which needs to be dereferenced on remote server not on local server

Sample curl call

```
curl http://<remote_ip>:2878/getdata --data "env=${ENV} linux_version=${LINUX_VERSION}"
```

Env variables {ENV}, {LINUX_VERSION} are present in remote server not on local server from which i am trying to call

I want to make curl like above but want those variables to be de referenced on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Use single, rather than double, quotes to inhibit expansion on the local system: `curl ... 'env=${ENV} ...'`. Now, whether or not they get expanded on the remote system depends on what that `getdata` URL does with the data. There is nothing about the HTTP standard which will cause those vars to be automatically expanded by the web server.